# Why do my frontend apps share cookies from backend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, jwt

I have a Laravel backend and two VueJS apps. I use Laravel passport for issuing jwt tokens, and storing them in cookies. I expected each of the frontend apps to have its own cookies. But when I log in to one app the same jwt cookie appears in both apps' storage and the user gets authenticated in both apps at once.

This is login method:

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

        if($user) {
            if ($user->isCustomer() && $request->input('scope') != 'customer') {
                throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Permission denied');
            }

            if(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('jwt', [$request->input('scope')])->accessToken;

                $cookie = \cookie("jwt", $token, 3600);
            } else {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException('Password mismatch');
            }
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('There is no such user');
        }

        return \response([
            'token' => $token
        ])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

When I perform login request the jwt cookie appears in both frontend apps' storages and has the same value:

[image: first app]

[image: second app]

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: __By default, cookies are scoped to the issuing domain, and on IE/Edge to subdomains.__

Comment: Can I rescope them somehow according to the receiving domains?

Comment: Doing too much work to get them to work on `localhost` is probably wasted effort because in production you will likely have your apps in different domains anyway. I suggest setting up each app in its own virtual host (check your webserver documentation on how to do this) and create "fake" DNS entries in your hosts file. (Yes you'd need to set up each front-end behind a proxy on the standard HTTP/HTTPS port)

Comment: In my minds, you must set cookies on front, not back. Back must return token as api response to vue, and vue set cookie to his domain

Comment: @apokryfos I have them deployed in production under different domain, but the cookie is the same with backend domain.